# Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error in PHP:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object
```

Source code:

```
<?php
$c1=103;//customer ID
$c2=104;//customer ID   
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stored_procedure_examples","root","");
// execute the stored procedure
$sql = 'CALL GetCredit($c1,$c2)';//passing customer ID 103 and 104 as parameter
$q = $conn->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Credit Limit</th>
</tr>
<?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $r['creditlimit'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

MySQL Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCredits(in p_cusno1 int(11),p_cusno2 int(11))
BEGIN
SELECT creditlimit  FROM customers WHERE customerNumber IN(p_cusno1,p_cusno2);
END$$
```

Note: if I pass the customer ID directly it works

if I pass indirectly by using variables like `c1` and `c2` it's throwing error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object
```

Comment: please put your query in double quotation. and this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 0):

pass the variables through double quotes, because single quotes don't get the value of variables.

```
change:
$sql = 'CALL GetCredit($c1,$c2)';

to:
$sql = "CALL GetCredit($c1,$c2)";
```